# How to add nexus 3rd part jar package to eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, nexus

I've added a 3rd party jar to nexus and modified my maven settings.xml to use that nexus repo, as follows:

```
     <profile>
      <id>dev</id>
      <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>local-nexus</id>
              <url>http://127.0.0.1:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
              <releases>
                  <enabled>true</enabled>
              </releases>
              <snapshots>
                 <enabled>true</enabled>
              </snapshots>
          </repository>
      </repositories>
  </profile>
```

Now I'd like my eclipse maven plugin to use nexus 3rd party jar, but eclipse maven repositories view of Project repositories center is still empty. I tried rebuilding the index, to no avail. Any hint ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure eclipse to use the settings.xml you have modified. You should be able to find it easily in preferences > maven